# mysql connection string in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

I want to connect mysql in C#.I add library of mysql. But database doesn't founded.

```
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;    
baglanti = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Data Source=" + Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "BMS Folder"), "BMS") + "\\ecsdatabase.sql; Read Only=False");
```

Comment: Have you tried to create the path to the .SQL Data outside of the ConnectionString? Have you tried to access it via File.Exists()?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Connection strings don't expect a path name to file, but the name of the database in the `DataSource` field.

I suspect that `DataSource=ecsdatabase` will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can get the connection String by right-clicking your Database in the Server-Explorer and navigating to "Properties". From there you could see the DataSource-String. Just copy it into your project.

If you want to make the path relative, you could use "|DataDirectory|".

Answer (score 0):

Check out [http://www.connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) There you will find pretty much any variant of connection string for MySQL.